# Why does the PPA not sync between Source and Binary?

Tags: apt, package-management, compiling

I want to install `libxml2-dev` to compiled to PHP but I get this error when I try:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:  libxml2-dev :
Depends: libxml2 (= 2.9.1+dfsg1-3ubuntu3) but 2.9.1+dfsg1-3ubuntu4.4 is to be installed 
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages
```

I found the last versions of source and binary lib in Synaptic Pakage Manager:

[image: Synaptic Package Manager]

Why is the source version `2.9.1+dfsg1-3ubuntu3`, but the binary is `2.9.1+dfsg1-3ubuntu4.4`?

How can I install `libxml2-dev`?

Comment: Which PPA are you using?

Comment: Canonical Partners, Independent, and some ppas for theme, webupd8, noobslab.

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu are you using? 2.9.1+dfsg1-3ubuntu4.4 is the current version of [libxml2-dev in Trusty](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise-updates/libxml2-dev).

Comment: By `lsb_release` command, I see my Ubuntu is `14.04.1 LTS`

Answer (score 0):

Mine seem to line up. I suggest that your local package lists need updating with a `sudo apt-get update`.

If that doesn't help, add the output of `apt-cache policy libxml2{,-dev}` to your question please.

```
$ apt-cache policy libxml2{,-dev} 
libxml2:
  Installed: 2.9.1+dfsg1-3ubuntu4.4
  Candidate: 2.9.1+dfsg1-3ubuntu4.4
  Version table:
 *** 2.9.1+dfsg1-3ubuntu4.4 0
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     2.9.1+dfsg1-3ubuntu4 0
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
libxml2-dev:
  Installed: 2.9.1+dfsg1-3ubuntu4.4
  Candidate: 2.9.1+dfsg1-3ubuntu4.4
  Version table:
 *** 2.9.1+dfsg1-3ubuntu4.4 0
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     2.9.1+dfsg1-3ubuntu4 0
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
```

Comment: After change mirror server to main server, run `apt-get update`, it get done! Maybe mirror server is not latest version! Thanks you! Thanks @Florian Diesch